# Obrigar a permitir o email na api do facebook

Tags: php, api, facebook, http

Olá.

Estou a usar a api (http) do facebook já algum tempo, mas detectei um problema há uns dias atrás... Existe pessoas a retirar a permissão de email o que depois causa inconsistências no sistema.

**Existe forma de obrigar a permitir ver o email?** Isto é, não permitir seguir em frente caso não deixe ver o email.

Estava a tentar outra solução. No callback ver se tem a variável email ou não. O problema é que o utilizador não consegue voltar a fazer login porque no facebook já fica guardado a sua preferencia de não permitir o email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei como esta usando e qual versão, mas a logica não muda muito, se fez algo como:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => '{app-id}',
    'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2'
});

try {
    $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph retornou um erro: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK retornou um erro: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

if (empty($user['email'])) {
      echo 'Esta página requer que você informe o seu e-mail';
      exit;
}

//Resto do script...
```

Agora se no primeiro acesso ainda tem o e-mail e apenas futuramente o usuário remove o e-mail, você pode salvar o e-mail em uma base de dados.

```
$user = $response->getGraphUser();

$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE idUser = ' . $user['id']);
if (false === $result) {
    echo 'Erro na query';
    exit;
}

$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

if ($data === NULL && empty($user['email'])) {
      //Emite erro se não houver usuário no banco e nem email no acesso
      echo 'Esta página requer que você informe o seu e-mail';
      exit;
} else if ($data === NULL && empty($user['email'])) {
      //Grava email no banco se ainda não existir
      if (false === mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO user (idUser, email) VALUES ($id, $email)")) {
           echo 'Erro ao inserir no banco';
           exit;
       }
} else if ($data !== NULL && false === empty($user['email']) &&
            $user['email'] !== $data['email']
) {
      //Atualiza email do banco de dados se ambos forem diferentes
      if (false === mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE user SET email = '" . $user['email'] . "' WHERE id = " . $data['id'])) {
           echo 'Erro ao atualizar o email';
           exit;
       }
} else {
      $user['email'] = $data['email']; //Seta a variavel vinda do banco na sua variavel principal
}

//Resto do script...
```

Note que o script é apenas ilustrativo, você pode usar qualquer banco de dados que estiver ao alcance do teu servidor, no caso usei um exemplo simples e talvez não esteja funcional, mas é apenas pra entender a lógica, acaso vá usar mysql então leia a documentação:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php